# Is there a way to target all textareas with a value using CSS only?

Tags: jquery, css, textarea, css-selectors

I imagined this to be straightforward, but I am unable to find anything that indicates I can use CSS to target non-empty textareas on a page.

I'm okay with JS if CSS absolutely does not support this, but even with jQuery I can't find a way to use a selector, but have to explicitly check for a .val().

*Some context: I have an optional textarea that expands on focus, but if the user does decide to type something, I don't want it to shrink again when focus leaves.*

Comment: If it wasn't for the optional nature of the `textarea` there'd be the [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:invalid) selector (the problem being it would require the `required` attribute on the element) selector (in supported browsers), as it is `:empty` is probably the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('textarea:empty')` is a nice way of doing it, but as I am dealing with textareas whose content may constantly change and be empty at one point and non-empty the next, this would still require checking every time the user focuses in and out of the textarea.

I ended up adding a class `.empty` to my textarea, and checking its value every time `.focusout` is fired:

```
$('textarea').focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') { $(this).addClass('empty'); }
  else { $(this).removeClass('empty'); }
  });
```

This way I can keep the styling in my stylesheets and the rules defined by `.empty` get used even after the user has typed something and decides to delete it all.

Answer (score 4):

Markup-wise, the `:empty` selector should allow you to select textareas that have absolutely no content, not even so much as whitespace or a line break. Conversely `:not(:empty)` should let you select non-empty textareas.

Selectors in CSS are mostly static though, meaning they don't account for dynamic changes such as if you edit a textarea's content after page load. Furthermore, a selector like `:empty` doesn't really account for a textarea's value so much as it checks for the presence (or absence) of content nodes in general, so I suspect it doesn't play well with forms.

If you need to apply styles dynamically based on the value of a form field, you'll need to use a script to check its value using `.val()` or something similar every time it updates.

Comment: Thanks, but the :empty selector is used to target elements without children nodes, and doesn't seem to work with input elements. I guess it would work if the content of the input is actually in the markup between the <textarea> tags, but in this case, it's not.

Comment: @Mohammad: there should be [no space in your selector](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AXMn9/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in jQuery like:

```
$('textarea:not(:empty)').css('color','red');
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Znj5x/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at `:invalid & :valid` CSS3 pseudo classes:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eAYsp/1/)

```
<textarea required="required"></textarea>

textarea:invalid{background:red}
textarea:valid{background:blue}
```

Comment: Indeed, but `required` has side-effects when it comes to submitting the form.

Comment: you still can remove required attribute before submitting the form

Comment: True, but it's not really in keeping with the CSS-only aspect of the question, is it?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `.filter()`?

```
    $("input").filter(function() { return this.value == ""; }).css('dosomething');
```