# Is it possible to use CSS selector for textarea value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to do this in JavaScript/jQuery but I am wondering if there's a way to do this in CSS?

I know we can target the placeholder containing a string using:

```
textarea[placeholder*="WORK"]{
    background: purple;
}
```

Is there something similar for the value?

I tried `textarea[value*="MY_STRING"]` but that didn't work probably because the value of the textarea is not an attribute unlike `input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent got anything. But if you really want to use the  value in the textarea you will have to duplicate the info perhaps by adding a data-info attribute and making the text similar to the value.  And then use the data attribute to select the specific textarea. This is not a good way to do it but just thought it might help

```
<textarea data-info="My String">My String</textarea>
```

css might be like this

```
textarea[data-info="My String"]{ ....}
```

Again this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: This is actually a good idea. One can set the `oninput` handler on the textarea which modifies the `data-info` as `this.dataset.info=this.value;`  and it would work without any external JS. The CSS can also use `*=` instead of `=` for `contains` behavior.

Answer (score 5):

No, as textarea currently only supports the following attributes:

```
autocapitalize 
autocomplete
autocorrect 
autofocus
cols
form
maxlength
minlength
placeholder
readonly
required
rows
spellcheck
wrap
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attributes

i.e nothing based off what the user does

Comment: Thanks. I just found this too which agrees: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002469/is-there-a-way-to-target-all-textareas-with-a-value-using-css-only

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `<input>` element for this by giving it a pattern and making it required, then using the CSS `:valid` pseudo-class. This does not work for `<textarea>` because it does not support the pattern attribute.

```css
input:valid{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^.*MY_STRING.*$" required/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my questions is about textarea which doesn't support pattern matching: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643417/how-to-validate-pattern-matching-in-textarea

Comment: @PranoyC I am aware of that. I was providing a workaround.

Comment: Ok thank you. Please leave the answer as it is as it might help future users who can use the workaround.